# Ionic header bar hides content

Tags: ionic-framework

I am new to Ionic and of course searched for a solution on SO and Google but no success.

I try to build a first simple app using following code:

```
<body>
        <ion-header-bar class="bar bar-header bar-dark">
          <h1 class="title">Settings</h1>
        </ion-header-bar>
        <ion-content class="has-header">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </ion-content>
    </body>
```

What happens is that the header overlaps the content and hides the first lines of text.

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is this all the code inside body? If not provide more because my codepen of this is working correctly.

Comment: Also what version of ionic are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the `has-subheader` class to your ion-content directive.

Comment: He shouldn't have to do that. The ion-content begins after headerbar as it is declared in the tag with has-header.

Comment: but I'm pretty sure doing so will solve the problem.

Comment: This will only add extra white space between content and actual header. This is just a work around, not a solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yavGkG) of their nightly build. It seems more like a problem with the ionic version you are running.

`<ion-header-bar>` and the classes you provide are correct, try updating ionic and see if that fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `<ion-view>` instead of `<body>` tags.

There you can also set the title, like:

```
<ion-view view-title="Settings">
<!-- Your content, etc goes here  -->
</ion-view>
```